# Arquivo php trabalhar sozinho de forma automática

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um arquivo php que envia informações para:

```
http://air.radiotime.com/Playing.ashx?partnerId=PARTNERID&partnerKey=PARTNERKEY&id=ID&title=MUSICA&artist=ARTISTA
```

Porém, só envia informações quando eu recarrego a página, existe alguma forma de deixar isso automático sem eu precisar estar no site? Ou seja, trabalhando sozinho.

Comment: Existem milhões de maneiras, uma delas é usar `while(1=1)` e dar um `ignore_user_abort(true)`. Uma outra é usando cronjob... Para definir qual é o melhor vai depender do objetivo disso (e se tem motivo para fazer isso), enfim, sem detalhes não dá para informar.

Comment: Se a máquina for linux, uma sugestão simples é a criação e um [cron job](http://www.vitorbritto.com.br/blog/agendando-tarefas-com-crontab/) que chamaria este script PHP a cada período que você especificar.

Comment: Acho viavel utilizar um cron job

Comment: Usei cron job, funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode executar esse script PHP por linha de comando.
Basta rodar o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
php caminho/para/o/arquivo.php
```

Ai você tem 2 opções, nesse script criar um loop infinito e deixar o arquivo sempre rodando.

```
while (1==1) {
    // Codigo que faz a request
}
```

Ou então configurar no cron (ou outro agendador de tarefas) para executar esse script em determinado intervalo de tempo.